# Fetch rows which has the same value in two columns for all the input values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a supplier table which has columns Item, `suppliername` and status. For the given items, I have to fetch the rows which has the same value in `suppliername` and status column only if the same values exists for all the given items.

For example, if the below is the table

```
Item    Suppliername      Status
A        S1               Created
A        S1               Approved
B        S1               Approved
B        S2               Created
C        S1               Created
C        S1               Approved
```

Input given are  Items 'A', 'B', 'C'

The output should be as below.

```
Suppliername      Status
S1                Approved
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm/approach or do you have one, but don't know how to write the according SQL query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Re: other commenters -- I answered this question because I feel the technique I used might not be obv. to a new SQL coder and thus they would be stuck unable to move forward or even provide a first test.  (Also, once you know this technique it is not that hard.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
WITH picklist(Item) AS
(
  VALUES ('A'),
         ('B'),
         ('C')
), grouping AS 
(
  SELECT T.Suppliername, T.Status, COUNT(*) AS C
  FROM TABLE T
  JOIN picklist ON T.Item = picklist.Item
  GROUP BY T.Suppliername, T.Status
)
SELECT Suppliername, Status
FROM grouping 
WHERE C = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM picklist)
```

If Values does not work on your platform you can use for SQL Server

```
 SELECT 'A' as Item
    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'B' as Item
    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C' as Item
```

and For Oracle (according to MT0)

```
 SELECT 'A' as Item FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'B' as Item FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'C' as Item FROM DUAL
```

Comment: `SELECT 'A'` is not valid in Oracle - you want `SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL`.

Comment: Hogan: this is a repeated issue with (some of) your answers to Oracle questions. Approximate answers (here is how you would do it in another SQL dialect, you figure it out for Oracle) is not OK in real life, so there is no reason it should be OK on SO. Others may feel differently, but for me this is a reason for automatic downvote. Either provide correct Oracle answers to questions clearly marked Oracle, or let others help.

Comment: It is also incorrect as it will get groups where there are two `A`s and a `C` but no `B` value.

Comment: @mathguy -- if it is wrong then it is wrong and should get a down vote.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @MT0 -- good point, I was assuming you could not have the item listed twice with the same status, but it is a mistake to assume this.

Comment: @mathguy -- it is not crazy for me to expect DBs to support VALUES constructor -- it is in the 92 standard.

Comment: @Hogan - I didn't say it's crazy. I am making a different point: since you don't work with Oracle (so you don't know what parts of the standard it implements, and you don't know what wonderful tools Oracle developed that are not part of the standard - like the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause) simply trust that there are enough Oracle practitioners here who will help the OP. By all means, post your suggestions without testing them (if you really can't test them), just don't be upset if I - or perhaps others - use the privilege of downvoting if we feel the answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5f58/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE CharList IS TABLE OF CHAR(1)
/

CREATE TABLE table_name ( Item, Suppliername, Status ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'S1', 'Created' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'S1', 'Approved' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'S1', 'Approved' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'S2', 'Created' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'S1', 'Created' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'S1', 'Approved' FROM DUAL
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Suppliername, Status
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY Suppliername, Status
HAVING CharList( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
       SUBMULTISET OF CAST( COLLECT( Item ) AS CharList )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5f58/5/0)**:

```
| SUPPLIERNAME |   STATUS |
|--------------|----------|
|           S1 | Approved |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT Suppliername, Status
FROM   table_name
WHERE  Item IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
GROUP BY Suppliername, Status
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT item ) = 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5f58/5/1)**:

```
| SUPPLIERNAME |   STATUS |
|--------------|----------|
|           S1 | Approved |
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT Suppliername, Status
FROM   table_name
WHERE  Item MEMBER OF CharList( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
GROUP BY Suppliername, Status
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT item ) = CARDINALITY( CharList( 'A', 'B', 'C' ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5f58/5/2)**:

```
| SUPPLIERNAME |   STATUS |
|--------------|----------|
|           S1 | Approved |
```